# Wrong calculation of lim of function by 2 variables

Tags: calculus, functions

may someone tell me where I was wrong (102 means that the lim doesn't exist or $=\infty$ or $=-\infty$)

$$\lim_{ x\to 9, y\to 1} \frac{\tan(y-1)\sin^2(x-9y)}{(x-9)^2+(y-1)^2}$$

$$\lim_{{x\to0}\atop{y\to0}}e^{4x/(x^2+y^2)}$$

I drew these functions using geogebra and I got it right

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @saulspatz I tried but wasn't successful

Comment: Thanks Robert, I hope my question is well written now. So where did I do wrong? on geogebra 3d I get that the lim for both is $\infty$

Comment: Does my edit of the second question convey what is intended?  I think I misread the screen print the first time; it's not terribly clear.

Comment: @saulspatz yes, thanks! may you check my answers?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  In the first line, you say you were wrong, and in the last, you say you were right.  What exactly are you asking?

Comment: my answers are wrong but if I draw the functions in geogebra I can see that the lim is 102

Comment: We can't tell you what you did wrong unless you show us what you did.  You should put each of these in a separate question, and show us your calculations.  I know you haven't learned MathJax, but we've given you a start.  I don't know how to help you otherwise.

Comment: I don't know to calculate lim until this moment and I must solve this using geogebra, so there is nothing to show except using geogebra